# What part of Spark return failed task to a different node?

Tags: apache-spark

When a task running on a node fails, Spark will automatically return the task to a different node. My Questions are:

- What part of Spark is responsible for that? Is it ApplicationMaster,
  driver, or ResourceManager?
- What is the procedure of recovering the failed task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a spark task is failed following things happen

1. Node manager at that machine try to rerun that task on same machine and also informs APPLICATION MASTER.
2. Based on speculative execution, application master may decide to run a duplicate task on another machine. Resource Manager does not restart the task
3. Task is restarted from beginning. Since all partitioned processed by that task were lost in that failure that happened earlier. Thats where spark RDD lineage comes in picture. spark takes spark lineage and tries to recreate partition which was lost as part of task failure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's so valuable for me. Last question: what if the worker or Node manager fails. Would ApplicationMaster run two tasks on two different machines based on speculative execution? Or it just runs one task?

Comment: it will run 2 tasks on 2 diff machines and accept whichever completes first